# How to increase the performance while downloding the blob to local storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have below code to download the JSON file which is in blob storage. Actually this below code takes more than a minute to download it in local folder, please suggest me to increase performance by refining this below code.

```js
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(“jsonfile_name"); 
string jsonString = string.Empty;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
blockBlob2.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
jsonString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(localfolderPath, FileMode.Create))
{
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
writer.Write(jsonString);
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is the size of the file you are downloading?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling [DownloadToFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtofile.aspx) as a minor improvement, but this still does not explain the download taking more than a minute. You should investigate if something is wrong on the client side or on the network. If you enable Azure Storage logging, you can compare Server latency and E2E latency to see whether Blob service was at fault or client/network. For more information on this, I would recommend looking at our [Monitor, diagnose, and troubleshoot Microsoft Azure Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/) article.